# SQL Query using Windowing Functions - Lead and Lag for insert & update output

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need a sql query to peform the below operations using Windowing function Lag and Lead.

For each Key, I need to perform the below Insert and update in the final output

**Insert Condition:**
1. By Default, LAYER_NO=0 , needs to be written in output.
2. If there is any change in the value of COL1,COL2,COL3, with respective to its precious record,then that records needs to be written in output.

Example: key_1 with layer_no=2, there is a change of value from 400 to 600 in COL3

**Update Condition:**
1. If there were NO changes in the value of COL1,COL2,COL3, with respective to its previous record,but there is a change in "DEPART column", this value needs to be updated in the output.

2.Even the LAYER_NO should be updated sequentially, after inserting the record with layer_no=0

Example: key_1 with layer_no=3, there were NO changes in COL1,COL2,COL3, But there is value change in DEPART column as "xyz" , so this needs to be updated in the output.

```
select * from input_table;   
+-----+--------+----+----+----+------+
|  KEY|LAYER_NO|COL1|COL2|COL3|DEPART|
+-----+--------+----+----+----+------+
|key_1|       0| 200| 300| 400|   abc|->default write
|key_1|       1| 200| 300| 400|   abc|
|key_1|       2| 200| 300| 600|   abc|--->change in col3,so write
|key_1|       2| 200| 300| 600|   abc|
|key_1|       3| 200| 300| 600|   xyz|--->change in col4,so update
|key_2|       0| 500| 700| 900|   prq|->default write
|key_2|       1| 888| 555| 900|   prq|--->change in col1 & col 2,so write
|key_3|       0| 111| 222| 333|   lgh|->default write
|key_3|       1| 084| 222| 333|   lgh|--->change in col1,so write
|key_3|       2| 084| 222| 333|   rrr|--->change in col4,so update
+-----+--------+----+----+----+------+
```

what will be the SQL query to generate the below output from input_table ?
Expected Output:

```
+-----+--------+----+----+----+------+
|  KEY|LAYER_NO|COl1|COl2|COl3|DEPART|
+-----+--------+----+----+----+------+
|key_1|       0| 200| 300| 400|   abc|
|key_1|       1| 200| 300| 600|   xyz|
|key_2|       0| 500| 700| 900|   prq|
|key_2|       1| 888| 555| 900|   prq|
|key_3|       0| 111| 222| 333|   lgh|
|key_3|       1| 084| 222| 333|   rrr|
+-----+--------+----+----+----+------+
```

Comment: Share with us what you have tried so far to produce the desired output table and you'll likely get responses to help correct it.

Comment: mysql <> sql server <> Oracle, please don't tag products not in use

Comment: Across all 3 platforms?

Comment: By "Insert Condition" do you mean a [column default](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF53355)? What have `lead` and `lag` got to do with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Dataframe - Windowing Function - Lag & Lead for Insert & Update output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205629/spark-dataframe-windowing-function-lag-lead-for-insert-update-output)

Comment: Do you actually want to insert or update anything, or are you just asking for a report on preexisting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by first working out the rows that have had their col1, col2 or col3 columns changed, and then by finding the latest depart value for the subsequent rows, like so:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'key_1' KEY, 0 layer_no, 200 col1, 300 col2, 400 col3, 'abc' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_1' KEY, 1 layer_no, 200 col1, 300 col2, 400 col3, 'abc' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_1' KEY, 2 layer_no, 200 col1, 300 col2, 600 col3, 'abc' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_1' KEY, 2 layer_no, 200 col1, 300 col2, 600 col3, 'abc' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_1' KEY, 3 layer_no, 200 col1, 300 col2, 600 col3, 'xyz' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_2' KEY, 0 layer_no, 500 col1, 700 col2, 900 col3, 'prq' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_2' KEY, 1 layer_no, 888 col1, 555 col2, 900 col3, 'prq' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_3' KEY, 0 layer_no, 111 col1, 222 col2, 333 col3, 'lgh' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_3' KEY, 1 layer_no, 084 col1, 222 col2, 333 col3, 'lgh' depart FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'key_3' KEY, 2 layer_no, 084 col1, 222 col2, 333 col3, 'rrr' depart FROM dual),
   changed_rows AS (SELECT KEY,
                           layer_no,
                           col1,
                           col2,
                           col3,
                           depart,
                           CASE WHEN LAG(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY layer_no) = col1
                                     AND LAG(col2) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY layer_no) = col2
                                     AND LAG(col3) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY layer_no) = col3
                                     THEN 0
                                ELSE 1
                           END changed_cols1_to_3
                    FROM   your_table),
    define_grps AS (SELECT KEY,
                           layer_no,
                           col1,
                           col2,
                           col3,
                           depart,
                           changed_cols1_to_3,
                           SUM(changed_cols1_to_3) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY ORDER BY layer_no) grp
                    FROM   changed_rows)
SELECT KEY,
       grp -1 layer_no,
       col2,
       col2,
       col3,
       MAX(depart) KEEP (dense_rank LAST ORDER BY layer_no) depart
FROM   define_grps
GROUP BY KEY,
         col1,
         col2,
         col3,
         grp;

KEY     LAYER_NO       COL2       COL2       COL3 DEPART
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------
key_1          0        300        300        400 abc
key_1          1        300        300        600 xyz
key_2          0        700        700        900 prq
key_2          1        555        555        900 prq
key_3          1        222        222        333 rrr
key_3          0        222        222        333 lgh
```

The `changed_rows` subquery checks col1, col2 and col3 to see if it has the same values as the previous row (no change) or not (change). We assign a value of 1 to changed rows and 0 to unchanged rows.

The `define_grps` subquery works out the running total of the `changed_cols1_to_3` column across all the rows per key. This has the effect of grouping each set of consecutive rows where cols 1, 2 and 3 are the same.

Finally, we can pick the last row for each group. The new layer_no is simply the grp number minus 1.